# Is there a closed form for  the characteristic polynomial of the graph cycle (of n edges and n summits) ?

Tags: spectral-graph-theory

Is there a closed form for  the characteristic polynomial of the graph cycle (of $n$ edges and $n$ summits)?

I know it for the graph path (it is a Chebyschev polynomial), but I couldn't find a closed form when adding the missing edge.

Comment: I can't imagine any book on spectral graph theory that doesn't give this example.

Comment: maybe i am misunderstanding something; a graph cycle has a circulant matrix as its adjacency matrix, with eigenvalues $2\cos(2\pi k/n)$, where $k=0,1,\ldots,n-1$, for the cycle $C_n$. So the char poly is fully determined. Maybe the OP means something else?

Comment: @Suvrit: The OP's question is: what is the polynomial with those roots?

Comment: @Igor: So basically you / the OP don't want the polynomial in factorised form, but rather expanded out, with closed forms for the coefficients? 

Comment: @Suvrit: I certainly do not want it, and am merely interpreting the OP's wishes.

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding. Yes, I wanted a closed form for the coefficients of the characteristic polynomial, but my main question was : is there a simple relation between the polynomials for graphs differing only by one edge, as in this case. 

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I use $\phi$ for characteristic polynomial, then
$$
\phi(C_n,t) = \phi(P_n,t) - \phi(P_{n-2},t) - 2.
$$
This follows from the formulas in Section 4.1 of "Algebraic Combinatorics" by yours truly, 
see in particular Exercise 5 in Chapter 4. (Sorry about the self-referencing, but I have
no recollection of seeing the formula elsewhere.) Since the coefficient of $t^{n-2r}$ in $\phi(P_n,t)$ is $(-1)^r\binom{n-r}{r}$, the above identity leads to a simple expression for the coefficients of $\phi(C_n,t)$.